# How to build a closed funnel of user steps in Big Query?

Tags: google-bigquery

Please help me with the BigQuery query. I need to build a closed funnel of user steps events in a mobile app for a week.

The table looks like this:
[image]

It is necessary to collect all unique users who have passed from step 1 to step 2 and so on to step 6 during this period. Between these steps, they could do something else, be distracted by other events. But what is important is the passage of each unique user through these steps in a given period of time.

Please tell me how to create such a funnel?

Comment: So to rephrase, you want to extract from your data the users that have passed through 'event_name': 'step 1', 'step 2', ... , 'step 6', in a week ?

Comment: In your process, if a user arrives at step 6, that means he had to to go through all the previous steps right? (No possibility to jump directly from 1 to 6?) In this case, the problem becomes filtering users who arrived at step 6 with less than a week since they passed step 1

Comment: Yes, I want ALL unique users who have gone through this path in a week and counted at every step.
As a result, get such a table  

step1 -10000     step2 - 500  step3 - 20   ets

Comment: yes, he must go through all the previous steps. he cannot go directly to step 6 or 4

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple ways of achieving this. Here is an approach using identical sample data, which is not the most optimal but is very self-explanatory and definite:

```
with data as (
   select 'a' as user_id, cast('2020-01-01 04:45:00' as timestamp) as event_timestamp, '1' as step_name
   union all
   select 'b' as user_id, cast('2020-01-01 04:50:00' as timestamp) as event_timestamp, '1' as step_name
   union all
   select 'a' as user_id, cast('2020-01-01 05:00:00' as timestamp) as event_timestamp, '2' as step_name
   union all
   select 'a' as user_id, cast('2020-01-01 05:15:00' as timestamp) as event_timestamp, '3' as step_name
   union all
   select 'b' as user_id, cast('2020-01-01 04:55:00' as timestamp) as event_timestamp, '2' as step_name
   union all
   select 'c' as user_id, cast('2020-01-01 04:58:00' as timestamp) as event_timestamp, '1' as step_name
   union all
   select 'a' as user_id, cast('2020-01-01 05:16:00' as timestamp) as event_timestamp, '4' as step_name
   union all
   select 'b' as user_id, cast('2020-01-01 05:16:00' as timestamp) as event_timestamp, '3' as step_name
),
data2 as (
   select a.user_id,  a.step_name step_1, b.step_name step_2, c.step_name step_3, d.step_name step_4 from ( select user_id, event_timestamp, step_name from data where step_name = '1') a
   left join data b on (a.user_id = b.user_id and a.event_timestamp < b.event_timestamp and b.step_name = '2')
   left join data c on (b.user_id = c.user_id and b.event_timestamp < c.event_timestamp and c.step_name = '3')
   left join data d on (c.user_id = d.user_id and c.event_timestamp < d.event_timestamp and d.step_name = '4')
)

select * from (

   select 'step_1' as event_name, count(distinct user_id) as n_users from data2 where step_1  is not null
   group by 1
   union all 
   select 'step_2' as event_name, count(distinct user_id) as n_users from data2 where (step_1  is not null and step_2 is not null)
   group by 1
   union all 
   select 'step_3' as event_name, count(distinct user_id) as n_users from data2 where (step_1  is not null and step_2 is not null and step_3 is not null)
   group by 1
   union all 
   select 'step_4' as event_name, count(distinct user_id) as n_users from data2 where (step_1  is not null and step_2 is not null and step_3 is not null and step_4 is not null)
   group by 1
)
order by 1
```

You can further optimize this based on your specific filters, conditions, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much! Only I do not have the exact time of the step. I cannot highlight it. I have a week. For a week, users go through these steps sequentially, and the time can be any for each user.

Comment: I have three small tables instead of a table "data". How can I then make three funnel steps out of them?

Comment: WITH s1 as (
SELECT 
   user_pseudo_id, user_id, event_timestamp, event_name
FROM `app.events_*`
WHERE event_name = "addToCart" AND
_TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20210519' AND '20210519'),
s2 as (
SELECT 
   user_pseudo_id, user_id, event_timestamp, event_name
FROM `app.events_*`
WHERE event_name = "begin_1" AND
_TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20210519' AND '20210519'
),
s3 as (
SELECT 
   user_pseudo_id, user_id, event_timestamp, event_name
FROM `app.events_*`
WHERE event_name = " begin_2" AND
_TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20210519' AND '20210519'
),